# Self-made calendar doesn't count the years right

Tags: javascript, function, calendar

i have been busy with a home-made calendar for understanding certain javascript stuff, and i encountered something which for me is very odd.

I have two functions linked to buttons which go to one year before, and one year after the current year.
I also have a function which opens a prompt so you can select any year you want.

The calendar works fine, the buttons work fine, except for one little thing.

Here is the code first:

```
year = 2014;

function last_year(year,month) {
parseInt(window.year -= 1);
yeartype(window.year,0);
}

function next_year(year,month) {
parseInt(window.year += 1);
yeartype(window.year,0);
}

function chooseYear(year,month) {
window.year = prompt("Which year do you want to see?");
yeartype(window.year,0);
}
```

yeartype is a function which checks if it's a leap year or not, and then makes the calendar for that specific year.

When i added the function chooseYear, it started to mess things up.

When i enter a year, it loads it. For example, 2020. When i press last_year after i used the chooseYear function, it goes to 2019 (which should happen), but if i press next_year after i used chooseYear, it goes from 2020 to 20201. And if i press last_year after that, it goes back to 20200. For some reason, if i use chooseYear, followed by next_year, it ADDS a number after the existing numbers. Going back a year doesn't give problems though.

It's a really long question, but it's a weird situation to explain. Does anyone know how i canmake it work properly?
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I guess you have some kind of conflict with one of your parameters. You pass `year` as a parameter but using the global variable `window.year`. So you're calculating the global one but (maybe) not that one from the parameter.

Comment: It was not the thing that was wrong, but you made me think! I figured that the prompt i opened in chooseYear for some reason didn't pass the input in the prompt as a number. Somehow the javascript read it as a string. I changed:

window.year = prompt("Which year do you want to see?");

into 

window.year = parseInt(prompt("Which year do you want to see?"));

Now it works.

It's solved thanks to you making me look from a different perspective.

Thanks!